What does "creating" refer to?
Foot rot is a sporadic infection of the soft tissues of the foot in dairy and beef cattle, creating a sudden onset of mild to severe lameness.
is “creating” in this sentence a cause and effect statement or does “creating” refer to “a sporadic infection”?

I don't see how those two options are different. A case of foot rot creates a sudden onset of lameness. You could replace it with which creates.

you could also replace it with causing or which causes. Same difference.

"which creates..." is a valid paraphrase of the original sentence but I think it obscures the very problem that seems to beset the OP. In approaching the sentence as one having a relative clause, the OP is looking for a relative-word that stands in for the noun in the main clause. Hence the question "What does 'creating' refer to?"  [my emphasis]

The participial clause headed by creating there expresses something that the infection does: it creates a sudden-onset lameness which can range from mild to severe.
"What does 'creating' refer to?" is not the proper question to ask, since creating does not refer to an antecedent noun.  The proper question is "What is the subject of the participle creating?"
Participles are forms of verbs, and verbs need subjects, "do-ers" of their action.
